# Uploading of photos in VTiger 6.5 doesn't show up

Tags: php, vtiger, vtigercrm

I installed VTiger 6.5 (patch 4.2). In Contacts modules I added an additional upload feature beside upload profile pic.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXj2e.png)

In the image, the part encircled in blue is the field I added. Now when I attached picture it is working and saving all picture in the storage folder, but I noticed that It is not saving in the database. Now since it was not saving in the database, the profile pic and the calling card pic in the view is missing.

Link is here, take note that I have this installed in my localhost.

```
http://localhost/crm__/index.php?module=Contacts&view=Detail&record=19&mode=showDetailViewByMode&requestMode=full
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSOde.png)

If you needed the code for the contacts.php or rather the controller then I can post it here. But since it was long I'll just skip that part for now and just show u the saving to database part.

```
        $sql2 = "insert into vtiger_attachments(attachmentsid, name, description, type, path) values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        $params2 = array($current_id, $filename, $this->column_fields['description'], $filetype, $upload_file_path);

        $result = $adb->pquery($sql2, $params2);
```

I reall don;t know much how to debug php in Vtiger as I cannot just insert an echo and die.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Please Open this file of **c:\xampp\php\php.ini** search this line into file

**;extension=php_fileinfo.dll** and remove semicolon(;) and save it

Answer (score 0):

Please check Vtiger installation requirements
https://wiki.vtiger.com/index.php/System_Requirements

for upload files in vtiger you need to install **mime_magic** or **fileinfo**
 extension on PHP.